# UITableView sections insertion

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with one section , Im trying to add more one section

```
 tableView.beginUpdates()     
 tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index:1) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)    
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

I've updated the numberOfSections and the numberOfRowsInSection , the number or rows would be 1 . but it doesn't work, and the CPU usage up to 100% for few minutes .

Comment: did you update the datasource accordingly first, then call tableView.insertSections ?

Comment: No , can you explain it . The table view already had it’s data source .

Comment: no problem,let say you datasource is an array ds = ["section0","section1"],and you now you would like to insert "section3".so 1.ds.append("section3").2.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index:2) as IndexSet, with: .automatic) . not tested yet on my side,but you can have a try

Comment: I’m trying to figure out what is that mean ds array , the data source is the view controller itself , I’ve updated the data source arrays .

Comment: so it works? ds just is a name of the array you were using for datasource,could be any,not a big deal.my point here is update the array first then you can start to insertSection.

Comment: you know , something weird , before I tried to make the insertion from the accessoryView , it would not work . but now I've tried to make the insertion from didSelectRowAt , it works fine .

Comment: weird.luckily it works now.

Comment: any way, thank you so much for your time .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215383/discussion-between-charlie-cai-and-shadi-asi).